# Find a random Local Drive and download files there

Tags: powershell, batch-file, download

As the title says, I want to find a random local drive and download some files inside the drive.

Well, thats my actual line:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {if($PSversionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 3) {Invoke-WebRequest http://download1475.mediafire.com/dgmccvd5felg/cu6x9bzhx3hmz78/Teste.jpg -OutFile atf3@~~.exe}}"
```

As you can see, I already have a way to download the files, but I want these files to be downloaded inside this random drive, and I need some help with that.

It will happen in another computer, so I don't have how to know nothing about the local drives, so prepare this script for any situation please, and I need that script to run in one single batch file.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  If the script is being executed from unknown computer, why wouldn't you just download the file to the directory the script is located in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick a random local drive and change the working directory to its root folder like this:

```
$root = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter 'DriveType=3 AND NOT DriveLetter IS NULL' | Get-Random).DriveLetter + '\'
Set-Loction $root
```

Comment: Just one more question, after that line, i will use 
'call "atf3@~~.exe" '
How can i save the random position to open this file?

Comment: @DaMonki Store the path in a variable before using it. See updated answer.